# Как сделать так,чтоб текст был внизу картинки

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так чтоб текст ( Что нужно учитывать при выборе ткани ) был внизу картинки ( хочу создать второй отдел сайта ),не используя margin, padding ?

Буду благодарен,если поможете

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    /* margin-left: 350px; */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(107, 107, 104, 0.493);
}

.logo {
    padding: 0.9em;
}

.navlist {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
.navlist a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    padding: 1.5em;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.navlist a:hover {
    transition: 0.8s;
    color: burlywood;
    font-size: 17px;
}
  
  .navlist a span
  {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .navlist a span::before
  {
    transition: width .9s;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: currentColor;
  }
  
  .navlist a:hover span::before
  {
    width: 100%;
  }

.num {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 730px;
    padding: 1.5em;
}

.socmedia {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 4px;
    color:  burlywood;
    transition: 0.8s;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 210px;
}

.instcont {
  transition: 0.8s;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.vkcont, .whatsappcont {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.vkcont:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.instcont:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.whatsappcont:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.coverimg img{
  position: absolute;
    /* width: 1920px;
    height: 965px; */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}

.headtextcover {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.maindesigncont, .buttonform {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.maindesigncont {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.designcurtaincover {
  background:  rgba(107, 107, 104, 0.493);
  background-size: 100px 20px;
  padding: 2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.buttonform1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(252, 252, 250, 0);
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: 0.8s;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.buttonform1 a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.buttonform1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.8s;
  color: burlywood;
  transition: 0.8s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonform1:hover .tchildbuttonform a {
  color: burlywood;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/css/mainpage.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>CURTAINS</h1>
        </div>

         <ul class="navlist" >
            <li><a href=""><span>О нас</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Услуги</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Материалы</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Наши работы</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Отзывы</span></a></li>
          </ul>

            <div class="num">
              <span>+8 987 626 99 70</span>
            </div>

          <div class="contacs">
            <div class="socmedia">
                     <div class="instcont">
                       <a href="">
                         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M224.1 141c-63.6 0-114.9 51.3-114.9 114.9s51.3 114.9 114.9 114.9S339 319.5 339 255.9 287.7 141 224.1 141zm0 189.6c-41.1 0-74.7-33.5-74.7-74.7s33.5-74.7 74.7-74.7 74.7 33.5 74.7 74.7-33.6 74.7-74.7 74.7zm146.4-194.3c0 14.9-12 26.8-26.8 26.8-14.9 0-26.8-12-26.8-26.8s12-26.8 26.8-26.8 26.8 12 26.8 26.8zm76.1 27.2c-1.7-35.9-9.9-67.7-36.2-93.9-26.2-26.2-58-34.4-93.9-36.2-37-2.1-147.9-2.1-184.9 0-35.8 1.7-67.6 9.9-93.9 36.1s-34.4 58-36.2 93.9c-2.1 37-2.1 147.9 0 184.9 1.7 35.9 9.9 67.7 36.2 93.9s58 34.4 93.9 36.2c37 2.1 147.9 2.1 184.9 0 35.9-1.7 67.7-9.9 93.9-36.2 26.2-26.2 34.4-58 36.2-93.9 2.1-37 2.1-147.8 0-184.8zM398.8 388c-7.8 19.6-22.9 34.7-42.6 42.6-29.5 11.7-99.5 9-132.1 9s-102.7 2.6-132.1-9c-19.6-7.8-34.7-22.9-42.6-42.6-11.7-29.5-9-99.5-9-132.1s-2.6-102.7 9-132.1c7.8-19.6 22.9-34.7 42.6-42.6 29.5-11.7 99.5-9 132.1-9s102.7-2.6 132.1 9c19.6 7.8 34.7 22.9 42.6 42.6 11.7 29.5 9 99.5 9 132.1s2.7 102.7-9 132.1z"/ id="inst"></svg>
                       </a>
                     </div>
                    <div class="vkcont">
                      <a href="">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M31.4907 63.4907C0 94.9813 0 145.671 0 247.04V264.96C0 366.329 0 417.019 31.4907 448.509C62.9813 480 113.671 480 215.04 480H232.96C334.329 480 385.019 480 416.509 448.509C448 417.019 448 366.329 448 264.96V247.04C448 145.671 448 94.9813 416.509 63.4907C385.019 32 334.329 32 232.96 32H215.04C113.671 32 62.9813 32 31.4907 63.4907ZM75.6 168.267H126.747C128.427 253.76 166.133 289.973 196 297.44V168.267H244.16V242C273.653 238.827 304.64 205.227 315.093 168.267H363.253C359.313 187.435 351.46 205.583 340.186 221.579C328.913 237.574 314.461 251.071 297.733 261.227C316.41 270.499 332.907 283.63 346.132 299.751C359.357 315.873 369.01 334.618 374.453 354.747H321.44C316.555 337.262 306.614 321.61 292.865 309.754C279.117 297.899 262.173 290.368 244.16 288.107V354.747H238.373C136.267 354.747 78.0267 284.747 75.6 168.267Z"/ id="vk"></svg>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="whatsappcont">
                       <a href="">
                         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z"/ id="whatsapp"></svg>
                       </a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="coverimg">
      <img src="static/images/tim-mossholder-taxHJ0zZxn8-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="maindesigncont">
      <div class="designcurtaincover">
          <p class="headtextcover">Дизайнер по шторам</p>
          <br>
        <p>Дизайн штор - это важный элемент декора комнаты, который может сделать ее еще привлекательней.<br>
          Дизайн интерьера все больше становится популярным, и шторы являются важной частью любого дома или офиса.<br> Они помогают создать уютную атмосферу, защитить от солнца и сохранить приватность.<br> Также, шторы могут быть использованы как элемент декора, чтобы подчеркнуть общий стиль интерьера.</p>
          <br>
          <p>Мы с радостью поможем вам выбрать и спроектировать шторы, которые будут соответствовать вашим потребностям и стилю.<br> Наша команда профессионалов имеет многолетний опыт работы в данной области и может предложить широкий спектр решений.</p>
          <br>
        <p>Мы работаем с различными типами тканей, от легких и прозрачных до плотных и затемняющих.<br> Кроме того, мы можем предложить широкий выбор стилей, от классических до современных и эксклюзивных.<br> Мы также готовы предложить профессиональный совет по цвету, фактуре и дополнительным элементам украшения.</p>
          <br>
      <p>Конечно же, мы не забываем о практической стороне проекта.<br> Мы учитываем ваши требования к освещению, приватности и вентиляции.<br> Кроме того, наша команда может предложить решения для автоматизации штор, чтобы создать максимальный комфорт.</p>
      <br>
         <p>Мы с радостью поможем выбрать лучшее решение</p>
         <br>
        <div class="buttonform">
          <div class="childbuttonform">
              <form action="https://youtube" target="_blank">
                 <button class="buttonform1"><span>Оставить заявку</span></button>
              </form>
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="secondpage">
    <div class="sptext">
      <span>Что нужно учитывать при выборе ткани</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    /* margin-left: 350px; */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(107, 107, 104, 0.493);
}

.logo {
    padding: 0.9em;
}

.navlist {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlist a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    padding: 1.5em;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.navlist a:hover {
    transition: 0.8s;
    color: burlywood;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.navlist a span {
    position: relative;
}

.navlist a span::before {
    transition: width .9s;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: currentColor;
}

.navlist a:hover span::before {
    width: 100%;
}

.num {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 730px;
    padding: 1.5em;
}

.socmedia {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: burlywood;
    transition: 0.8s;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 210px;
}

.instcont {
    transition: 0.8s;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.vkcont,
.whatsappcont {
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.vkcont:hover {
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.instcont:hover {
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.whatsappcont:hover {
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.coverimg img {
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 1920px;
    height: 965px; */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}

.headtextcover {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.maindesigncont,
.buttonform {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.maindesigncont {
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.designcurtaincover {
    background: rgba(107, 107, 104, 0.493);
    background-size: 100px 20px;
    padding: 2em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.buttonform1 {
    border: 1px solid rgba(252, 252, 250, 0);
    background-color: burlywood;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    transition: 0.8s;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.buttonform1 a {
    color: black;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.buttonform1:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: 0.8s;
    color: burlywood;
    transition: 0.8s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonform1:hover .tchildbuttonform a {
    color: burlywood;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.sptext {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>CURTAINS</h1>
        </div>

        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href=""><span>О нас</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Услуги</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Материалы</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Наши работы</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Отзывы</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="num">
            <span>+8 987 626 99 70</span>
        </div>

        <div class="contacs">
            <div class="socmedia">
                <div class="instcont">
                    <a href="">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                            <path
                                d="M224.1 141c-63.6 0-114.9 51.3-114.9 114.9s51.3 114.9 114.9 114.9S339 319.5 339 255.9 287.7 141 224.1 141zm0 189.6c-41.1 0-74.7-33.5-74.7-74.7s33.5-74.7 74.7-74.7 74.7 33.5 74.7 74.7-33.6 74.7-74.7 74.7zm146.4-194.3c0 14.9-12 26.8-26.8 26.8-14.9 0-26.8-12-26.8-26.8s12-26.8 26.8-26.8 26.8 12 26.8 26.8zm76.1 27.2c-1.7-35.9-9.9-67.7-36.2-93.9-26.2-26.2-58-34.4-93.9-36.2-37-2.1-147.9-2.1-184.9 0-35.8 1.7-67.6 9.9-93.9 36.1s-34.4 58-36.2 93.9c-2.1 37-2.1 147.9 0 184.9 1.7 35.9 9.9 67.7 36.2 93.9s58 34.4 93.9 36.2c37 2.1 147.9 2.1 184.9 0 35.9-1.7 67.7-9.9 93.9-36.2 26.2-26.2 34.4-58 36.2-93.9 2.1-37 2.1-147.8 0-184.8zM398.8 388c-7.8 19.6-22.9 34.7-42.6 42.6-29.5 11.7-99.5 9-132.1 9s-102.7 2.6-132.1-9c-19.6-7.8-34.7-22.9-42.6-42.6-11.7-29.5-9-99.5-9-132.1s-2.6-102.7 9-132.1c7.8-19.6 22.9-34.7 42.6-42.6 29.5-11.7 99.5-9 132.1-9s102.7-2.6 132.1 9c19.6 7.8 34.7 22.9 42.6 42.6 11.7 29.5 9 99.5 9 132.1s2.7 102.7-9 132.1z"
                                / id="inst">
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="vkcont">
                    <a href="">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                            <path
                                d="M31.4907 63.4907C0 94.9813 0 145.671 0 247.04V264.96C0 366.329 0 417.019 31.4907 448.509C62.9813 480 113.671 480 215.04 480H232.96C334.329 480 385.019 480 416.509 448.509C448 417.019 448 366.329 448 264.96V247.04C448 145.671 448 94.9813 416.509 63.4907C385.019 32 334.329 32 232.96 32H215.04C113.671 32 62.9813 32 31.4907 63.4907ZM75.6 168.267H126.747C128.427 253.76 166.133 289.973 196 297.44V168.267H244.16V242C273.653 238.827 304.64 205.227 315.093 168.267H363.253C359.313 187.435 351.46 205.583 340.186 221.579C328.913 237.574 314.461 251.071 297.733 261.227C316.41 270.499 332.907 283.63 346.132 299.751C359.357 315.873 369.01 334.618 374.453 354.747H321.44C316.555 337.262 306.614 321.61 292.865 309.754C279.117 297.899 262.173 290.368 244.16 288.107V354.747H238.373C136.267 354.747 78.0267 284.747 75.6 168.267Z"
                                / id="vk">
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="whatsappcont">
                    <a href="">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                            <path
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z"
                                / id="whatsapp">
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
        <div class="coverimg">
            <img src="static/images/tim-mossholder-taxHJ0zZxn8-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="maindesigncont">
            <div class="designcurtaincover">
                <p class="headtextcover">Дизайнер по шторам</p>
                <br>
                <p>Дизайн штор - это важный элемент декора комнаты, который может сделать ее еще привлекательней.<br>
                    Дизайн интерьера все больше становится популярным, и шторы являются важной частью любого дома или
                    офиса.<br> Они помогают создать уютную атмосферу, защитить от солнца и сохранить приватность.<br>
                    Также, шторы могут быть использованы как элемент декора, чтобы подчеркнуть общий стиль интерьера.
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>Мы с радостью поможем вам выбрать и спроектировать шторы, которые будут соответствовать вашим
                    потребностям и стилю.<br> Наша команда профессионалов имеет многолетний опыт работы в данной области
                    и может предложить широкий спектр решений.</p>
                <br>
                <p>Мы работаем с различными типами тканей, от легких и прозрачных до плотных и затемняющих.<br> Кроме
                    того, мы можем предложить широкий выбор стилей, от классических до современных и эксклюзивных.<br>
                    Мы также готовы предложить профессиональный совет по цвету, фактуре и дополнительным элементам
                    украшения.</p>
                <br>
                <p>Конечно же, мы не забываем о практической стороне проекта.<br> Мы учитываем ваши требования к
                    освещению, приватности и вентиляции.<br> Кроме того, наша команда может предложить решения для
                    автоматизации штор, чтобы создать максимальный комфорт.</p>
                <br>
                <p>Мы с радостью поможем выбрать лучшее решение</p>
                <br>
                <div class="buttonform">
                    <div class="childbuttonform">
                        <form action="https://youtube" target="_blank">
                            <button class="buttonform1"><span>Оставить заявку</span></button>
                        </form>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="secondpage">
        <div class="sptext">
            <span>Что нужно учитывать при выборе ткани</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```